# C# SqlDataReader close method

Tags: c#, dao, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

Which of these methods is better for closing [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

 while (reader.Read())
 {
 }
 reader.Close();
 reader.Dispose();
```

or

```
SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
while (reader.Read())
{
}
```

or there are another further closing methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way of handling this is the `using` statement:

```
using(SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)) {
    while (reader.Read())
    { 

    }
}
```

This way the object gets disposed correctly (and you don't need to call `Close()`).

Answer (score 2):

A `using` statement is the best practice in such situations from my experience. It makes sure the connection is properly closed even if an exception happens somewhere inside.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Of course you could do the same with a `try { } finally { }`, which is what the `using` statement does internally. I found it's generally a good idea to get in the habit of always handling readers via the `using` statement to avoid the possibility of leaked connections.

Answer (score 0):

Use first scenario if you work with reader within one method and second one if you pass reader as return value (not within one scope).

Answer (score 0):

the doc you need is this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close.aspx

To quote: "You must explicitly call the Close method when you are through using the SqlDataReader to use the associated SqlConnection for any other purpose."